# Problems with Google Analytics - Tracking not installed, but tracking, but no real time

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I wanted to install google analytics on my new site. I've set up the site, and pasted the code into my html web page and got it online. I'm using the Universal code version.

When I first put it up I put the code just before the  but after uploading it, the real time views didn't work and it told me 'Tracking Not Installed' so i used Googles Tag Assistant which told me that there was a critical error - HTTP Response Error (something along those lines).

I then removed the code and put it just before the  tag, when uploading it now, real time views still do not work, but it appears to have started to collect data, views, users, etc. When I know use googles tag assistant it tells me there are no problems just a suggestion that it should be in the head. Inside Google Analytics it is still telling me that 'Tracking Not Installed'.

Does it just take time to update? (been around 3 hours since first adding the code)

The website a one page site using css cheat script and things a long that line (lots of javascript) could this be a problem? (I didn't create the site).

I've doubled checked the account code and thats correct and also the http/https in the settings is set correctly to http.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code I'm using:

```
 <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'REMOVED', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just put the code in, then it normally takes from 24-48 hours for the status to change. If you can see Real-Time events tracking, say, with your own visits for example, then you should be good, and you can ignore the error message. How do you know that the tracker is collecting "data, views, users, etc."? Also, it's best practise to put the tracker within the head tags.

Comment: I CAN'T see real time events, and it says "Tracking Not Installed" but the data is showing, when I go to reporting and choose today it shows me that i've had 38 page views, 5 users, and 6 sessions and this data does increase every so often. Should I wait 24 hours? I've got adblocker disabled and on the website via my laptop and iPhone but when on real time events in google analytics theres nothing.

The reason i don't have it in the <head> is that when I did it also did not work but when using Googles Tag Assistant it told me there was a http response critical error?

Comment: I would say don't worry about the Real-Time report, as long as you are getting the data. Now you will need to check to see if it is accurate. And, yes, usually waiting helps a lot with Google products. :) There has been some problems in the past with RT reports, and I wouldn't be surprised if there's something wrong again. But that said, I'm not familiar with GA and mobile apps and it would be worth investigating.

Comment: The error I got before was: "Error: No HTTP response detected", I still get it every so often (1/10 times i visit the site) even with the code in the </body> not sure if It could be hosting related, but i'll leave it for a bit and see how it goes.

Comment: As an update - Real time views is now working and the users/sessions/page views keep updating so ima assume its okay.

Comment: Good stuff! Yeah, I've seen too often where you just need to give Google some time to get its act together. :)

Comment: I wanted to add a few specific details that I experienced. I installed the code for a new property and sent some page views and events from my local development server. Nothing showed up. 24 hours later, the reports showed the data, but page views and events did not show up in the real time report. A few days later, real time page views and events started working. So, I can echo what others have said—it does seem to just take time (but make sure you are actually sending data to the right place or the waiting may not help).